# ‘:colnames yes’ not working?

Tags: org-babel

I tried the example from `(info "(org) Environment of a Code Block")`:

```
#+NAME: less-cols
| a |
|---|
| b |
| c |

# I changed the value of ‘:colnames’ to _yes_.
#+BEGIN_SRC python :var tab=less-cols :colnames yes
  return [[val + '*' for val in row] for row in tab]
#+END_SRC
```

But the resulting table is still the same as when `:colnames` is `nil`:

```
#+RESULTS:
| a  |
|----|
| b* |
| c* |
```

Am I missing something?

---

###### Background

I’m writing my SQL notes.
**The resulting table contains some underlines**, e.g.,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql
 SELECT underline_1, underline_2
 FROM MyTable;
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| underline_1  | ...
|--------------+------
|     xx_x     | ...
|     yy_y     | ...
```

**An underline will be interpreted as the beginning of a subscript.
So I want to replace them with `\under`s**, thus tried the following code:

```
#+NAME: underline-escaper
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp  :var resulting-table='(("_"))  :colnames yes
  (mapcar (lambda (cell)
            `(,(string-replace "_" "\\under" (car cell))))
          resulting-table)
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC sql  :post underline-escaper(*this*)
 SELECT 'underline_1' AS "underline_1";
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
|   underline_1    |
|------------------|
| underline\under1 |
```

But the column name is still “underline_1”.

Comment: Maybe worth to report it via `M-x report-emacs-bug`?

Comment: @ManuelUberti : Thanks for your suggestion. But I'm not sure; it might not be a bug, but rather a misunderstanding of the document on my part (I've only been using Org Babel for less than half a month).

Comment: Not a bug (it is documented on the above page), but confusing nevertheless: the opposite of `yes` is `no`, not `nil`. `nil` and `yes` are more-or-less equivalent: they are exactly equivalent if there is an `hline` in the second row; they differ a bit if there isn't such an `hline`.

Comment: Actually, there may be  a bug: `nil` and `yes` seem exactly equivalent experimentally; so it may be that the doc is wrong.